# Do solidity conversions use gas? And tools for testing gas

Tags: solidity, gas, evm

Say I have two functions:

```
function add(uint256 x, uint256 y) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 sum = x+y;
        return sum;
    }

function add(uint256 x, uint256 y) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 sum = x+y;
        return uint256(sum);
    }
```

Does the below use more gas? I assume the EVM does not store the type of the variable. Is that true?

In general, what are good tools for testing gas usage of contracts.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, conversions do cost gas. Even it is sometimes recommended to use uint256 instead of uint8 because converting uint8 to uint256 is more expensive than just using uint256.

Since you are converting `uint256` to `uint256` it won't cost any extra gas.

You can use [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) to test gas usage. It has a [static analysis tool](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/static_analysis.html) and you can also run the functions and see their gas usages.